# Class won't serialize using GWT-RPC?

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, gwt-rpc

Here's the class I'm trying to send:

```
public class DummyClass implements Serializable, IsSerializable {

  private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();


  public DummyClass() {
    // stuff
  }
  public Object getValue(String key) {
    return properties.getValue(key);
  }
  public void setValue(String key, Object value) {
    properties.put(key, value);
  }
}
```

But when I try to send it as a parameter to a method in GWT RPC, I get an umbrella exception.

```
  DummyClass dummy = new DummyClass();
  dummy.setValue("foo", "bar");
  ServiceImpl impl = Gwt.create(SampleService.class).doSomething(dummy);
```

I could remove the generic types specified in the `Map properties`... but other than `Object` or `Serializable` there's no restriction to what could be stored in the properties map.

Instances of the class serialize just fine using Java's standard serialization.

Also, there's no warnings or errors shown by the GWT compiler.

Is there anything anyone can point out that I can try to get this to work?

Comment: The basics of Java serialization: Asking Java to serialize the type Object is like giving the bank teller a blank cheque and telling the teller you wish to bank in the cheque. Never encapsulate/embed an indefinite Object within a RPC data transfer object.

Comment: So then how could I send a Map of String keys to various values (types such as Date, String, Integer)?  This serializes just fine using Java serialization...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to replace the `java.lang.Object` return type of `getValue()` and parameter type of `setValue()` methods with something more specific (e.g. `java.io.Serializable`).

Note also you are fine if your object implements only `Serializable` (no need to implement `IsSerializable` besides it.).

Comment: Serializable is terribly general, and will cause the compiler to find _all_ classes that implement Serializable and are on the sourcepath. This will in turn cause field serializers to be generated for all of them and all of their subclasses. Be sure this is really what you want before causing this particular brand of bloat.

Comment: Right - Indeed, a more specific type should be provided.

Comment: Could you please provide the stack trace of your exception?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I scrapped everything and just made a DTO to contain all the fields individually... the problem was definitely the "Object" or "Serializable" type declaration... the GWT compiler would go through and compile every `object` or `serializable` on the classpath.

Comment: Another option you can use is to have dummy async methods or fields in already serializable types that reference types that are allowed. That is enough of a hint to the compiler that these other types can be sent over the wire.